# Transitive action and isotropy groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a transitive action of $G$ on the finite set $X$. How can I show that is equivalent to the natural action of $G$ on $G/G_x$ where $G_x$ is the isotropy group, i.e. $G_x$ = {$g\in G, gx=x$}?

I've seen that if two elements of $X$ are in the same orbit that their  isotropy groups are conjugate.

Can anybody give me some hints?

**Note**: The natural action of $G$ on $G/H$ of course is the one that sends the class $aH$ to $gaH$

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to define a bijection between $X$ and $G/G_x$ that respects the action, i.e. a map $\varphi : X \to G/G_x$ that is bijective and satisfies $\varphi(gy) = g\varphi(y)$ for all $g \in G$ and all $y \in X$.
As the orbit and $G/G_x$ have the same finite size, it is possible to find a bijection - already a good sign. :)

As $G$ acts transitively on $X$, we have that for every $y \in X$ there exists a $g_y \in G$ with $gx = y$. Try to show that defining $\varphi(y) := g_yG_x$ will have all the desired properties.